# Error con Trim() en Visual Studio C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

hace un tiempo vengo programando un proyecto escolar en C# mientras me guio de videos en youtube. Apenas estoy aprendiendo, y en este momento me encuentro con un error en el metodo Trim().

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El video del cual me estoy apoyando tiene el mismo codigo, pero sin el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Speech.Recognition; // reconocedor de voz
using System.Speech.Synthesis; // NOA
using BibliotecaNOA;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NOA_VIRTUALASSISTANT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer NOA = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        List<Comandos> lista = new List<Comandos>();
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); //microfono

            Choices comandos = new Choices();

            GrammarBuilder GB = new GrammarBuilder();
            GB.Append(comandos);

            Grammar gramatica = new Grammar(GB);

            rec.LoadGrammar(gramatica);
            rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            rec.SpeechRecognized += Rec_SpeechRecognized;

        }
        
        private void Rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Comandos c in lista)
            {
                if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.6)
                {
                    if (c.Comando.ToString().Equals(e.Result.Text.ToString()))
                    {
                        NOA.Speak(c.Comando.ToString());

                        if (c.Accion.Trim().Length > 0 && c.Accion != null)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(c.Accion.ToString());
                        }
                        
                    }

                    if (c.Respuesta.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        NOA.SpeakAsync(c.Respuesta.ToString());
                    }

                    
                }              
            }
        }

        private void llenarLista()
        {
            SqlConnection con = ConexionDB.ObtenerConexion();
            List<Comandos> lista = new List<Comandos>();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Comandos;"), con);

            SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rs.Read())
            {
                lista.Add(new Comandos(rs.GetInt32(0), rs.GetString(1), rs.GetString(2), rs.GetString(3)));
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private string[] cargarComandos()
        {
            string[] Comandos = new string[0];

            SqlConnection con = ConexionDB.ObtenerConexion();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT Comando FROM Comandos;"), con);

            SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rs.Read())
            {
                Array.Resize(ref Comandos, Comandos.Length + 1); //Reemplazar y añadir los comandos en la base de datos
                Comandos[Comandos.Length - 1 ] = rs.GetString(0);
            }

            return Comandos;
        }

        private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            SonarClick();

            if (BTSettings.IsMouseOver)
            {
                NOA.SpeakAsync("Ver configuración");
            }

            if (BTComandos.IsMouseOver)
            {
                NOA.SpeakAsync("Añadir comandos");
            }
                        
        }

        private void SonarClick()
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.EfectoSonido == true)
            {
                var uri = new Uri("@*../Sounds/OverMouse.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                var player = new MediaPlayer();

                player.Open(uri);
                player.Play();
            }
        }
        
        private void BTComandos_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigComandos CC = new ConfigComandos();
            CC.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien me podria ayudar o tal vez corregir si poseo algun error adicional? Se lo agradeceria demasiado. Muchas gracias.
..................................................................................................................................................

Comment: el trim solo se aplica a tipos de datos string, y lo estas aplicando a tipos de datos que no lo son, revisa bien

Comment: Mira que en los videos con los cuales me guio, tienen el mismo codigo pero no sufren de ese error.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo como texto

Comment: completo? o solo el fragmento del error...

Comment: @CamiloAndresMartinezMoreno lo minimo y necesario para que se pueda reproducir tu problema en los IDE's de los demas.

Comment: Lo lamento ahi ya esta el codigo

Comment: Te falta agregar esta clase `Comandos` . A modo de sugerencia, no repitas los nombres, tienes varias variables que se llaman "comando" o perecido y con diversos tipo de datos

Comment: Gracias, vere si logro solucionarlo

Comment: Tienes Comandos por un lado como variable y Comandos por el otro lado como objeto. ¿Que es Comandos? Puedes poner su definición?

Comment: Menú Ver - Lista de errores, el error que aparezca ahí puede ser útil para poder determinar lo que puede estar pasando y cómo resolverlo y de esta forma añadir: Me muestra el error... etc.,

Comment: Ya logre resolver el error. Muchas gracias a todos.